# Keep getting Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when a section of the sheet is deleted

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of my code is really simple.  It is designed to hide and unhide certain cells when a user is submitting form.  When a users wishes to start over again and clear data from more than one cell at a time, they are met with the Run-time error '13' Type mismatch.  Below is the code, can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 And Target.Value = "A" Then
    Application.Columns("F:G").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 And Target.Value = "B" Then
    Application.Columns("F:P").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 And Target.Value = "C" Then
    Application.Columns("F:P").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 And Target.Value = "D" Then
    
    Application.Columns("F:P").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 And Target.Value = "E" Then
    
    Application.Columns("F:P").Select
    Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   
End If
```

Comment: Please take the very basic troubleshooting step of identifying which line this occurs on

Answer (score 1):

Try isolating B2 from a possibly multi-cell Target.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(2, "B")) Is Nothing Then
        Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Select Case Cells(2, "B").Value2
            Case "Exceptions Reviewer"
                Columns("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "CAT Payouts Tracker Entry", _
                 "CAT Payouts Tracker Supervisor", _
                 "Agent Error Review", _
                 "Agent Error and Exceptions Reviewer"
                Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Type mismatch happens when one of the cells contains an error

`#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!`

Try testing for them as well

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target.Cells(1)

        If .Column = 2 And .Row = 2 And Not IsError(.Value2) Then

            Select Case .Value2

                Case "Agent Error and Exceptions Reviewer", _
                     "Exceptions Reviewer"

                        Columns("F:G").Hidden = True

                Case "CAT Payouts Tracker Entry", _
                     "CAT Payouts Tracker Supervisor", _
                     "Agent Error Review"

                        Columns("F:P").Hidden = True

            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch also regularly occurs when Target.value is checked and target is more than a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

the very *translation* of your code could be the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub ' exit if changed cell is not "B2" one only

    Select Case Target.value2
        Case "Exceptions Reviewer"
            Columns("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "CAT Payouts Tracker Entry", "CAT Payouts Tracker Supervisor"
            Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "Agent Error Review", "Agent Error and Exceptions Reviewer"
            Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

which would "cumulate" columns hiding/un-hiding

for instance should you need any "B2" cell content change to hide/un-hide the corresponding columns while un-hiding all the others, then you would use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub ' exit if changed cell is not "B2" one only

    Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' un-hide all columns for start
    Select Case Target.value2    
        'now hide columns as a consequence of cell B2 content
        Case "Exceptions Reviewer"
            Columns("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "CAT Payouts Tracker Entry", "CAT Payouts Tracker Supervisor"
            Columns("F:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End Select
End Sub
```